# Archivos xml independientes

Tags: vb.net

he buscado por todo lado, he intentado por mi misma, tengo la siguiente duda ya se como escribir archivos xml, el problema es que necesito que por cada escritura que haga me genere un archivo por aparte pero no se como hacerlo, por ejemplo ya hice archivo1.xml, si vuelvo a completar el formulario seria archivo2.xml y asi sucesivamente. Alguien me podria dar una idea como realizarlo por favor. Dejo parte de codigo realizado, gracias. Tiene que ser en tiempo de ejecucion.

```
                       Dim configuracionArchivo As New XmlWriterSettings

                    configuracionArchivo.Indent = True



                    Using escribiendoFactura As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("Facturas.xml", configuracionArchivo)
                        With escribiendoFactura


                            'Write the xml declaration
                            .WriteStartDocument()


                            .WriteStartElement("Facturas")

                            .WriteStartElement("Factura")


                            '.WriteStartElement("FechaCompra")
                            '.WriteString(lblFecha.Text)
                            '.WriteEndElement()

                            'Nodos de factura
                            .WriteStartElement("CedulaJuridica")
                            .WriteString(txtCedulaJuridica.Text.ToString)
                            .WriteEndElement()

                            



                            .WriteEndElement()

                            .WriteEndDocument()

                            .Flush()
                            .Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que necesitas, debes generar el nombre del archivo de manera dinámica porque como lo tienes actualmente siempre va a escribir sobre el archivo llamado `Facturas.xml`

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, si en realidad se trata de facturas, éstas generalmente tienen un número y pudieras hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente:

```
Dim configuracionArchivo As New XmlWriterSettings
dim nombreXml as string
...
nombreXml = $"Factura_{numeroDeFactura}.xml"
Using escribiendoFactura As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(nombreXml, configuracionArchivo)
...
```

Otras ideas pueden ser:

- Manejar un contador de archivo y componer el nombre de forma similar a la sugerencia anterior
- Concatenarle `DateTime.Now` al nombre del archivo.

**Actualización**

En vista de tu comentario relacionado con el intento de hacer un contador, a continuación encontrarás un ejemplo que puede servir de base o inspiración para crearlo.

El manejo de un contador requiere que la información del proximo número se guarde en alguna parte, en este ejemplo voy a utilizar un archivo en la misma carpeta de los xml, pero puede ser una base de datos o cualquier medio que sirva para almacenar información.

Es importantisimo tener en cuenta que guardar en un archivo, como en este ejemplo, no es un método infalible si se intenta utilizar por varios procesos al mismo tiempo.

En primer lugar se deben crear dos funciones una para leer el número guardado y la otra para guardar el proximo número.

```
'Primero se declara una constante para el nombre del archivo contador
'yo elegí este nombre, pero puede ser cualquiera
Const nombreDeArchivoContador = "contador.bin"

'Luego la función para guardar el número
Public Sub GuardarContador(numero As Integer)
    numero += 1
    File.WriteAllBytes(nombreDeArchivoContador, BitConverter.GetBytes(numero))
End Sub

'Después la función para leer el próximo número
Public Function LeerProximoNumero() As Integer
    Dim numero As Byte()
    Dim proximoNumero As Integer = 1
    If File.Exists(nombreDeArchivoContador) Then
        numero = File.ReadAllBytes(nombreDeArchivoContador)
        proximoNumero = BitConverter.ToInt32(numero, 0)
    End If
    Return proximoNumero
End Function
```

Ya con las funciones auxiliares creadas, la forma de utilizarlas sería la siguiente:

```
    Dim nombreXml As String
    Dim proximoNumeroDeArchivo As Integer

    Dim configuracionArchivo As New XmlWriterSettings
    configuracionArchivo.Indent = True

    Try
        proximoNumeroDeArchivo = LeerProximoNumero()
        nombreXml = $"Factura{proximoNumeroDeArchivo}.xml"
        Using escribiendoFactura As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(nombreXml, configuracionArchivo)
            With escribiendoFactura

                'Instrucciones para crear el contenido del Xml

            End With
        End Using

        GuardarContador(proximoNumeroDeArchivo)

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Instrucciones si la creación del xml 
        'o la actualizacion del archivo contador falla
    End Try
```

Comment: Tengo una estructura de datos que hace lo de numero de factura, y se va iterando ella sola, es una columna que hice para un datagridview, pero no sabria como utilizarlo para este caso. Se encuentra en otra clase.

Comment: @Keylor, el número de factura puedes enviarlo como parámetro al método que genera el XML

Comment: Lo realize con un contador pero no sigue despues de 1, se queda.

Comment: @Keylor, acabo de editar mi respuesta con un nuevo ejemplo